# Importing jQuery-mockjax with Ember-CLI - Brocfile not read

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bower, ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm trying to load `jquery-mockjax` into my test suite and followed the instructions on http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies.

I have placed a `Brockfile.js` in the root of my ember app:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

if (EmberApp.env() !== 'production') {
  app.import( app.bowerDirectory + '/jquery-mockjax/dist/jquery.mockjax.js', { type: 'test' } );
}

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

But it seems like the ember CLI is totally ignoring the file - I even tried adding a syntax error to trigger a build error. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ember CLI as of (1.13) does not actually read the `Brocfile.js`. But rather `ember-cli-build.js`.

Comment: I have created [an issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4479) to get the docs updated.

Comment: Docs are fixed as of https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/434dad63b58d2cbd5ffdb027ee34ff566e0b29c1

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by having `jquery-mockjax` in both `package.json` and `bower.json`